# Can someone help check if I evaluated my integral right?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The integral given to be evaluated is $\int 6x\cdot\mathrm{arctanh}(x)\,dx$.

I tried to evaluated and got the following answer:

$$3x^2\operatorname{arctanh}x + 3x -3\ln\,\bigl\lvert(1+x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigr\rvert + c$$

I used some trig substitutions and integration by parts to find it. Did I get it right or no?

Thank you.

Comment: When simply verifying a computation, I would use Wolfram|Alpha (wolframalpha.com). Enter the following into the input field: "integrate 6x*arctanh(x)"

Comment: A good way to check if you antidifferentiated correctly is to ... differentiate!

Comment: Your antiderivative is correct, but not in a fully simplified form.

Comment: I checked by differentiation and its right.

Comment: @heropup  How would i simplify it? Care to help me? lol

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $y = \tanh^{-1} x$; that is to say, $$x = \tanh y = \frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y} = \frac{e^y - e^{-y}}{e^y + e^{-y}}.$$  Hence $$0 = x(e^y + e^{-y}) - e^y + e^{-y} = (x-1)e^y + (x+1)e^{-y},$$ or equivalently, $$e^{2y} = \frac{1+x}{1-x}.$$  Therefore, $$y = \tanh^{-1} x = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}, \quad |x| < 1.$$  Now observe that $$\begin{align*} \log \left| \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right| &= \log \left| \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x} \sqrt{1+x}} \right| = \log \left| \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}} \right| = \log \left| \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \right| = \frac{1}{2} \log \left| \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right| \\ &= \tanh^{-1} x. \end{align*}$$  This immediately leads to the desired simplification.

Answer (score 0):

I get:

$3 \left(\left(x^2-1\right) \tanh ^{-1}(x)+x\right) + C$.